# Manipulating Google sheet api using Dart

Tags: dart, flutter, google-sheets-api

I couldn't find interresting ressources of how to use dart language to acess and manipulate **Google Spreadsheets** using googleapis package. Can anyone show help me by showing me a code example please ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Import the sheets package from googleapis:

```
import 'package:googleapis/sheets/v4.dart' as sheets;
```

Then, create the SheetsApi object:

```
var api = new sheets.SheetsApi(yourAuthorizedClient);
```

[This is a page on the SheetsApi object.](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.sheets.v4/SheetsApi-class.html) It contains the `spreadsheets` property. You can follow the links down the hierarchy until you find the method you need. [The complete list of classes are located here.](https://pub.dartlang.org/documentation/googleapis/latest/googleapis.sheets.v4/googleapis.sheets.v4-library.html) If you need any further clarification, let me know.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, and I am sorry to be late , I was too busy with some other stuff.
Could you show me exactly what is yourAuthorizedClient object please ?

Comment: thanks a lot for your help ,  it's okey for authentification.
Could you please show me how can I access and search in a specific row/column of the sheet and modify the content of a given cell , please ?

Comment: It's in the SheetsApi link I gave you. You just have to go down the properties and see what methods/attributes to call to figure out how to do that